# scala & mongoDB - how to count records with salat?

Tags: scala, mongodb, salat

Is it possible to issue a count() query, with several conditions, using salat library?

right now I'm just doing something like

```
def countByPoll(pollId: String, option: Int): Int = {
  dao.find(
    MongoDBObject("pollId" -> pollId, "option" -> option)
  ).size
}
```

But I'm sure a count would perform much better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at [salat sources](https://github.com/novus/salat/blob/master/salat-core/src/test/scala/com/novus/salat/test/dao/SalatDAOSpec.scala) and it was easier than expected

```
def countByPoll(pollId: String, option: Int): Long = {
  dao.count(MongoDBObject("pollId" -> pollId, "option" -> option))
}
```